# Python catch a turtle target mistake

Tags: python, python-turtle

Python catch to a turtle

```py
import turtle
import time
import math
from random import randint

font= ('Arial', 16, 'normal')

My_screen = turtle.Screen()
My_screen.bgcolor("light blue")
My_screen.title("Aim screen")

turtle_instance = turtle.Turtle()

turtle_instance2 = turtle.Turtle()
turtle_instance2.penup()
turtle_instance2.hideturtle()

turtle_instance3 = turtle.Turtle()
turtle_instance3.penup()
turtle_instance3.hideturtle()

score=0

My_screen.addshape("ezgif.com-resize.gif")

turtle_instance.shape("ezgif.com-resize.gif")

speed = 1

num = math.floor(My_screen.numinput("Timer", "Enter the seconds", minval=0, maxval=59))
stop = False

turtle_instance.penup()
turtle_instance.setposition(randint(-300,300),randint(-300,300))

def change_position():
    turtle_instance.hideturtle()
    x = randint(-300,300)
    y = randint(-300,300)
    turtle_instance.penup()
    turtle_instance.goto(x,y)
    turtle_instance.pendown()
    turtle_instance.showturtle()

def update_score():
    global score
    score = score + 1
    turtle_instance3.clear()
    turtle_instance3.write(score, font=("Arial", 15))

def spot_clicked(x,y):

    global num
    if num > 0:
        update_score()
        change_position()
    else:
        turtle_instance.hideturtle()

My_screen.listen()
My_screen.onclick(spot_clicked, 1)

while True:
    turtle_instance2.sety(300)
    turtle_instance2.setx(-30)
    turtle_instance2.write(str(num), font=("Arial", 50))
    turtle_instance2.sety(370)
    turtle_instance2.setx(-50)
    turtle_instance2.write("Time Left:", font=("Arial", 15))
    num -= 1
    time.sleep(1)
    turtle_instance2.clear()

    if num <= 0:
        turtle_instance2.clear()
        turtle_instance2.sety(320)
        turtle_instance2.setx(-90)
        turtle_instance2.write("Time Over", font=("Arial", 30))
        time.sleep(5)
        turtle_instance2.clear()
        break
    print(num)
    My_screen.update()

turtle.mainloop()
```

Guys i need help. No matter where I press, the score goes up. I want only when i click on the target.
I think problem is def spot_clicked global num if num > 0: update_score() change_position() else: turtle_instance.hideturtle() code.

Comment: the indentation of the code has gone wrong.  please fix and repost it...  (python needs indentation).

Comment: the `My_screen.onclick(spot_clicked, 1)` refers to `spot_clicked` which then runs `update_score` every time....  so you need to implement a check that the mouse is clicked in the correct area of the screen....

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your program is you are watching for clicks on the window when you should be watching clicks on the target itself.  You can invoke `onclick()` on the screen or an individual turtle.  Below is a rewrite of your code that includes this change:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randint

SMALL_FONT = ('Arial', 15, 'normal')
MEDIUM_FONT = ('Arial', 30, 'normal')
LARGE_FONT = ('Arial', 50, 'normal')

def change_position():
    target.hideturtle()
    x = randint(-300, 300)
    y = randint(-300, 300)
    target.goto(x, y)
    target.showturtle()

score = 0

def update_score():
    global score

    score += 1
    score_keeper.clear()
    score_keeper.write(score, align='center', font=SMALL_FONT)

def update_time():
    time_keeper.undo()
    time_keeper.write(seconds, align='center', font=LARGE_FONT)

def target_clicked(x, y):
    if seconds > 0:
        update_score()
        change_position()

def action():
    global seconds

    seconds -= 1

    if seconds <= 0:
        target.hideturtle()

        time_keeper.clear()
        time_keeper.sety(320)
        time_keeper.write("Time Over", align='center', font=MEDIUM_FONT)
    else:
        update_time()
        screen.ontimer(action, 1000)  # 1 second = 1,000 milliseconds

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor("light blue")
screen.title("Aim screen")
# screen.addshape("ezgif.com-resize.gif")

target = Turtle()
target.penup()
target.setposition(randint(-300, 300), randint(-300, 300))
# target.shape("ezgif.com-resize.gif")
target.shape('turtle')

score_keeper = Turtle()
score_keeper.hideturtle()
score_keeper.penup()

seconds = int(screen.numinput("Timer", "Enter the seconds", minval=0, maxval=59))

time_keeper = score_keeper.clone()

time_keeper.sety(370)
time_keeper.write("Time Left:", align='center', font=SMALL_FONT)
time_keeper.sety(300)
time_keeper.write(seconds, align='center', font=LARGE_FONT)

target.onclick(target_clicked)

action()

screen.mainloop()
```